# Python in hadoop and Oozie

Tags: python, hadoop, oozie

I am trying to import a python UDF in my pig script. When running the pig script manually in grunt shell the script is working fine.

But when I run it through Oozie, it is showing some error with the Python UDF. How to resolve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as u mention UDF is working fine with Pig Shell, which means the UDF is fine, but while accessing the same via Oozie, the Pig script is not able to find the UDF location, Could you please share the details Log of failure.
these will help to fix the issue